# How can I set connect and read timeouts on a SOAPConnection call?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

Title says it all. Relevant code looks like this:

```
SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
URL endpoint = new URL("http://*******/webservice.asmx?WSDL");
SOAPMessage soapACK = soapConnection.call(createSOAPLink(dataID), endpoint);
```

Comment: I don't see the point. You don't need a URLStreamHander to set timeouts.

Comment: What is the correct method to handle the timeout or how to set the timeout correctly?

Comment: Just set it on the HttpURLConnection. Get rid of the stream handler thing altogether.

Comment: I have put my codes in modified section. My challeng now how to pass the endpoint for soapConnection.call(createSOAPLink(dataID), endpoint); and also how to throw the inner catch error to the calling function ?

Comment: *Don't* catch it, of course. Let the caller catch it. I don't understand your question about the endpoitn but it seems to me you're working at the wrong level.

Comment: Ok let me rephrase my whole question is I am calling a soap webservice. If you see this line SOAPMessage soapACK = soapConnection.call(createSOAPLink(dataID), endpoint);. So I need to pass the url which is in the variable endpoint. The problem is need to set a timeout for the webservice else the calling function which is a  socket programme get into waiting too long causing a lot of close_wait. So I hope I made it clear about what I need to what is the best to be done.